# Trouble with using subviews in iOS development

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller, subview

I've been struggling trying to use subviews in my iOS development. I've been trying to follow best practices by putting all of my UI and layout code in subviews but it has been rather tricky for me and I need an answer on how I should properly go about this because I can't seem to find anything online that will directly answer my question.

I have a view that has a picture in the background, two text fields that are to be customized and a button is customized to have a white border around it. My subview blurs the background, designs the two text fields and the button all which is shown on one XIB file. I connect this view to the view on my storyboard, I need to be able to control drag from the button shown from the uiview file on the storyboard to my viewController to create a action for the button. The viewController file belongs to the view on the storyboard, not the one in the XIB file. So, I have a outlet connection for that button in my subview file and I need an action connection for that button in my viewController file. Obviously I can't do this because that button is part of the XIB file. If someone could tell me how to go about this differently by using subviews and storyboards, so I can design this button but also use it for actions in my viewController file all while still following the MVC pattern? If I'm doing this whole thing wrong or anything, any separate suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the subview code:

```
@IBDesignable class SignUpView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    configure()
}

func configure() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]

    //Add blur
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

    self.image.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    //Design text fields
    designTextField(usernameTextField, placeHolder: "Choose username")
    designTextField(passwordTextField, placeHolder: "Choose password")

    signUpButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    signUpButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
    signUpButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.7).CGColor

    addSubview(view)
}

func designTextField(textField: UITextField, placeHolder: String) {
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolder, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])

}

func addBorder(textField: UITextField) {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    border.opacity = 0.7 as Float
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
}


func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SignUpView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
    }
}
```

And the viewController code:

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//The action below needs to be connected to the button from the subview file
@IBAction func toggleSignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

}

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include what you were going to say after "is the following:" @Quantaliinuxite

Comment: The way to go about XIB (and keep in mind that you should first become accustomed to the storyboard and building views directly into the storyboard before going for XIB's) is the following: 
1-Build your view in the XIB.
2-Create a UIVIew  subclass - say "UIViewSub"
3-Set the XIB file owner to "UIViewSub"
4-override the init:coder and init:frame methods of UIViewSub, in them load your custom view from Nib, and set the `view`  property of UIViewSub to the your custom view.
5-You now have a reusable view object! To use it in a view controller, simply create a new instance of UIViewSub

Comment: Ok right, so I want to access the button I created in the "UIViewSub" in my view controller. So if I create a new instance of UIViewSub in my view controlller, how do I access that button and then create an action for it in my view controller? @Quantaliinuxite

Comment: You hook your outlets to the class UIViewSub and then access those directly in the controller. For example simply hook up your IBOutlet, call it rightButton and in the UIVIewController call mysub.rightButton.setTarget:

Comment: Not sure I can do that, for example lets say I have this variable declared in my view controller file:                                                                                      var subView = UIViewSub()                                                                                And then from here how do I create the action for the button outlet from the UIViewSub class? @Quantaliinuxite

Comment: Could you write a little more code for that? I'm still not quite getting how to access the variable correctly and create the action @Quantaliinuxite

Comment: I see your signup view has a sign up button outlet -- this is the way to go. Now in the controller call `signupView.signupButton.addTarget:`